# CentOS 6.9 brightness change don't work

Tags: linux, centos, intel-graphics, brightness, backlight

I have Intel HD 620 graphics card on my laptop. I have installed CentOS 6.9, but I can't change brightness of my monitor.

On Windows 10 it works without any problem. In my case `/sys/class/backlight` is empty, commands like `acpi_osi=` do not help. When I go to a screen settings I see my resolution (FHD), 0 Hz and an unknown monitor.

Is it a problem with drivers? Maybe CentOS 6.9's kernel is too old and do not support my generation of CPU (i5 7200u) and GPU (620)?